# FCKeditor extension in mediaWiki is Throwing Error

Tags: php, mediawiki, fckeditor

I'm trying to add FCKeditor extension in mediaWiki and I followed all the instructions that are written in their documentation 
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FCKeditor_(Official)

but it throws me this error.

**Strict Standards**:  Declaration of FCKeditorParser::makeImage() should be compatible with that of FCKeditorParserWrapper::makeImage() in **C:\www\wiki\extensions\FCKeditor\FCKeditorParser.body.php** on line **707**

**Strict Standards**:  Declaration of FCKeditorParser::parse() should be compatible with that of FCKeditorParserWrapper::parse() in **C:\www\wiki\extensions\FCKeditor\FCKeditorParser.body.php** on line **707**

Answer (score 1):

I have carried out the following changes in FCKeditorParser.body.php

Line 338: function makeImage ($nt, $options **,$holders=false**)

line 488: function parse ($text, **Headlining** $title, **ParserOptions** $options, $linestart = true, $clearState = true, $revid = zero)

Answer (score 1):

It seems your PHP is running in strict mode. The latest version of FCK Editor seems to have issues with strict PHP. See here [FCK Editor Extension Talk](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension_talk%3aFCKeditor_%28Official%29#1.16_and_latest_revision_not_working).

Answer (score 0):

You should double check all your path variables in [LocalSettings.php](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php), especially [$IP](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$IP).

In the extension itself you should verify that $wgFCKEditorExtDir and $wgFCKEditorDir are set correctly.